# Apps Script - Error Msg - The OAuth identity of this script has been deleted

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script, runtime-error

I'm getting the error message:

[image: OAuth Identity]

When I run the `doGet()` from the script editor.  I get:

[image: Identity Deleted]

I think I was testing some code for OAuth, but I have no idea how this happened or what I can do to solve this problem.

The `exec` version has the same problem, and publishing a new version, didn't change anything.

If I try to go to the developers console from the Resources menu, I get the error message.

[image: Failed Console]

Is there any fix to this?  Do I need to make a copy of the file, and write-this off as now unusable?

Answer (score 2):

I saw this the other day. It came from a script that I had changed the project ID to one I had created in the developer console. As this was only a test I deleted the project but hadn't revoked access to the script. It gave me this error.